# how can i give shadow to the com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout?

Tags: android, material-design, shadow, android-textinputlayout

I tried with elevation but not getting shadow to the upper portion of TextInputLayout. I want to get shadow like below picture:

[image]

Is there any way to get this shadow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how can i give shadow to the com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout?

You can wrap your `TextInputLayout` inside `Cardview`

SAMPLE CODE

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:cardCornerRadius="20dp"
        app:cardElevation="10dp">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/textField"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="User name">

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: can i get responsive text size or margin,padding,height using dp in android  or any other way to get this? @ Nilesh

Comment: This will cause the error view (setError) to be wrapped by the CardView.